# Set Opacity of Custom Tiles Over Google Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have loaded my custom tiles to display over Google Maps.  Any ideas how to set the opacity of them?  I retrieve my image tiles from a URL, add this as a drawable to my itemizedOverlay, then add the itemizedOverlays to my Overlay object.  There is no draw method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I make my bitmap a `BitmapDrawable` and then set the alpha.

```
Bitmap bit = some bitmap;
BitmapDrawable bd;
bd = new BitmapDrawable(bit);
bd.setAlpha(128);
```